# What causes people to feel depressed without there being a problem?

Tags: emotion, abnormal-psychology, depression

I have noticed that some people have lives that appear perfectly fine, yet they feel depressed. In my specific case the feeling typically  lasts for a few days and then magically disappears, only to reappear a couple of weeks later.

- In the absence of a real problem (e.g., loss of a close friend, physical sickness, etc), what causes these periods of negative affect?

Comment: I assume you are *not* talking about Major Depression, correct? Major Depression is rare without external stresses, but "normal depression" is common in all individuals without extreme stressors

Comment: @BenBrocka: Indeed, not Major Depressions. In fact, not anything that would be labeled as a depression, because (in my case) it only lasts for a couple of days at most.

Comment: You should take a look at this [question about endogenous versus exogenous reasoning in depression diagnosis](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/981/29). Your question might in-fact be a duplicate of that, but I haven't thought too closely about it.

Comment: Poor diet and lack of exercise. Or maybe you are getting just smart enough to grasp the pointlessness of your present form of existence. Good news - all of those are easily addressable by making life changes.

Comment: Related: [Why does a person feel sad without knowing the reason?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/5334/7001)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Their lives are perfectly fine" is a hard to test thing. Hard to compare. How people feel and respond is deeply contextual.

However there are several potential reasons:

- They may be 'wired' to feel stress or respond emotionally (i.e. Due to the way their brain has developed).
- A feeling of not being in control (This is often hard to perceive from outside and removed from concrete factors). The causes and triggers of this are varied and complex.
- A physical response. e.g. Things like a sensitivity to Gluten can cause incredible changes to our emotions and physiology. Often this manifests in good and bad periods.
- Negativity can be a reflection of the context or surroundings. Those same people may appear positive in a different context.
- Mental illness can manifest in uneven patterns. This spans from mild (common) to severe symptoms.

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to point out that there is a clear difference between a psychological depression and an existential one. I would like to point out the definitions of James Park of the University of Minnesota; please have a look at the [table at the bottom of this page.](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~parkx032/XP39.html)

So then, people with perfectly fine lives might well end up with a "clinical existential" depression.

Comment: I really like this, your introduction of existential vs psychological depression.  I would have said endogenous vs reactive, but this is another perspective and I really like it +1

Comment: Thank you Skippy. Always nice to know one´s comments are appreciated :-)

Comment: of course! I always try to welcome people.. and you've really struck an interesting cord for me.. there are a lot of unanswered questions here, feel free to potter and answer at your leisure :) *hint hint lol*

Comment: Hehe - fair enough and very welcoming of you. I take it slow, as I find some posts here a little heavy on the over-psychologising. Trying to be helpful and positive.

Comment: have a look at this http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5016/is-the-a-difference-between-existential-depression-and-endogenous-depression

Answer (score 2):

Some people with "without a problem" have fallen under **Gut Health/Gut Microbiota**.

See study:

[***"A randomized controlled trial to test the effect of multispecies probiotics on cognitive reactivity to sad mood."***](http://www.drperlmutter.com/study/randomized-controlled-trial-test-effect-multispecies-probiotics-cognitive-reactivity-sad-mood/)

> **"Conclusion: These results provide the first evidence that the intake of probiotics may help reduce negative thoughts associated with
>   sad mood. Probiotics supplementation warrants further research as a
>   potential preventive strategy for depression."**

Also see: ***[Depression, The Microbiome & Leaky Gut](http://www.drperlmutter.com/depression-microbiome-leaky-gut/)***

**References:**

- http://www.drperlmutter.com/study/randomized-controlled-trial-test-effect-multispecies-probiotics-cognitive-reactivity-sad-mood/#sthash.mtkhAYRd.dpuf
- http://www.drperlmutter.com/depression-microbiome-leaky-gut/
- Brain Maker: The Power of Gut Microbes to Heal and Protect Your Brain–for Life, Dr. David Perlmutter,  Kristin Loberg